# How to test implicit ModelState validation in C# dotnet Core WebApi

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-webapi, .net-6.0

I have a Web Api setup with the dotnet core net6.0 (and only a dependency on Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core)

In a controller, I have a CreateUser POST action that uses an object (Contact) with  data annotations within it to trigger ModelState validation automatically (it works even without registering filters the API).

I am failing to do a simple test of this Controller for the case where the incoming object does not have the correct properties (example: bad email).

All other test cases work perfectly.

### How to test the invalid HTTP 400 case correctly ?

```
[ApiController]
[Route("user")]
public class UserController : Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ControllerBase
{
    private readonly IUserUseCases _useCases;

    public UserController(IUserUseCases useCases)
    {
        _useCases = useCases;
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<ActionResult<IContact>> CreateUser(Contact contact)
    {
       return Ok(await _useCases.CreateUser(contact.Email));
    }
}
```

The Contact class is like this:

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
public class Contact
{
  [Required]
  [EmailAddress]
  public string Email { get; set; } = String.Empty;
}
```

How to test ModelState validation properly using unit tests?
Because as of now, it works and fails as expected with a HTTP 400 if the email is invalid :

```
{
  "type": "https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.5.1",
  "title": "One or more validation errors occurred.",
  "status": 400,
  "traceId": "00-ed9330d5127642d59342cd20bacf677e-9cfbb16b760cd6c8-00",
  "errors": {
    "Email": [
      "The Email field is not a valid e-mail address."
    ]
  }
}
```

Currently the Unit Test looks like this:

```
public class UserControllerUnitTests
{
    [Fact]
    public async Task ShouldReturnHttp400WithInvalidEmailContact()
    {
        // input
        string email = "john@smith.com";
        string firstName = "John";
        string lastName = "Smith";

        // expected output
        IContact expectation = new Contact()
        {
            Email = email,
        };

        var loggerMock = new Mock<ILogger<UserController>>();
        var userUseCaseMock = new Mock<IUserUseCases>();

        userUseCaseMock.Setup(mock => mock.CreateUser(email)).ReturnsAsync(new Contact() { Email = email });

        var controller = new UserController(userUseCaseMock.Object);
        var output = await controller.CreateUser(new Contact() { Email = email });

        var outputResult = output.Result as OkObjectResult;
        Check.That(outputResult).IsNotNull();
        Check.That(outputResult!.StatusCode).IsEqualTo(StatusCodes.Status400BadRequest);
    }
```

What I understand is that testing the controller directly won't activate the ModelState auto validation feature  directly.

But then, how to test that kind of model state validation in the latest aspnet core net6.0 framework ?

Comment: Usually you would test validation in a separate unit test. If you're both testing the controller and validation (and maybe more stuff), you're talking about an integration test, or even an application test in the case of an API. And it looks like you want to write a unit test for Core ASP.NET functionality: don't. You're not responsible for unit testing ASP.NET, Microsoft is. If there was a chance that ASP.NET was broken, nobody would use it.

Comment: @JHBonarius I agree however if it's in the specs that a specific form on input must be rejected, I must validate that the specs are still OK with the current implementation, then I need to do an integration test just for that because if I lose an important model restriction feature it's not good.

Comment: As a unit test you would check if `DataAnnotation` attributes are set on the model and -separately- if the model validation is enabled, which for API controllers you would check by looking for the `ApiControllerAttribute`. That implies the filter is enabled. [see the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/#automatic-http-400-responses). You don't need to test the functionality, because that's done by Microsoft. OF course you can write an API test, but that's not a Unit Test, thus requires another framework.

Comment: The validation takes place before the controller method is actually called. In your test you call the CreateUser method, which is not responsible for the validation. You need an integration test so that the request will be validated before it goes to the method or you can use fluent validation (or even your own one) and unit test your validators.